# Keep files newer than latest 10

Tags: vbscript

I'm writing a VBScript which will be deleting files with extension: '.bac' older than top 10.
I currently have written code to delete files older than 5 days and only if in the folder are more than 12 files but it delete all old files.
My target is to keep top 10 files with extension: '.bac' even if they are older than 5 days, because they are backup of my database (one is copy of configuration base and the second one is copy of product base, so 5 files need to be config backups and 5 files need to be product backups).

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim oFSO, oFolder, sDirectoryPath
Dim oFileCollection, oFile, sDir
Dim iDaysOld

'Specify Directory Path From Where You want to clear the old files
sDirectoryPath = "D:\Backup"

'Specify Number of Days Old File to Delete
iDaysOld = 5

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sDirectoryPath)
Set oFileCollection = oFolder.Files

'***********************BG File count*************************
Dim strDirectory, nThreshold, counter, extension, msgtext
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, Logfile

'file extension to look for
extension = "bac"

'directory to look in
strDirectory = "D:\Backup"

counter = 0

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
  If LCase((objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile))) = LCase(extension) Then
    counter = counter + 1
  End If
Next
'***********************End of file count*********************

If counter > 12 Then
  For each oFile in oFileCollection
    'This section will filter the text file as i have used for for test
    'Specify the Extension of file that you want to delete
    'and the number with Number of character in the file extension

    If LCase(Right(Cstr(oFile.Name), 3)) = "bac" Then
      If oFile.DateLastModified < (Date() - iDaysOld) Then
        oFile.Delete(True)
      End If
    End If
  Next
End If
Set oFSO = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing
Set oFileCollection = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
```

Comment: In Ruby that is one line, vbscript sucks for this kind of jobs

Dir.glob('c:/backup/*.bac').sort_by{|file| File.ctime(file)}[10..-1].each{|file| File.delete(file)}

Comment: Can you send whole code to do this in ruby and tell me if it's possible to setup scheduled task to run ruby

Comment: this IS the whole code, you can run it straight from the command line or put this line in a .rb script, if you include ruby in the tags and add some indication in your question I'll give some extra instructions, now I can't answer or I'll get downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to compile a list of the 10 most recent files, e.g. like this:

```
n    = 10 'number of files to keep
fldr = "D:\Backup"

ReDim mostRecent(n-1)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each f In fso.GetFolder(fldr).Files
  If fso.GetExtensionName(f) = "bac" Then
    For i = 0 To n-1
      If IsEmpty(mostRecent(i)) Then
        Set mostRecent(i) = f
        Exit For
      ElseIf f.DateLastModified > mostRecent(i).DateLastModified Then
        For j = n-2 To i Step -1
          If Not IsEmpty(mostRecent(j)) Then Set mostRecent(j+1) = mostRecent(j)
        Next
        Set mostRecent(i) = f
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End If
Next
```

and then delete all files that are not in that list in a second loop:

```
'create a lookup table to simplify filename checking
Set lut = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 0 To n-1
  If Not IsEmpty(mostRecent(i)) Then lut.Add mostRecent(i).Name, True
Next

For Each f in fso.GetFolder(fldr).Files
  If Not lut.Exists(f.Name) Then f.Delete
Next
```

---

Another (probably simpler and faster) approach is to shell out, create a directory listing with the `dir` command in a temporary file, then read the file list from that temporary file:

```
n    = 10 'number of files to keep
fldr = "D:\Backup"

Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sh.Run "%COMSPEC% /c dir /a-d /b /o-d /tw """ & fldr & """\*.bac >temp.txt"

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("temp.txt")
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  filename = f.ReadLine
  If f.Line > n Then fso.DeleteFile fso.BuildPath(fldr, filename)
Loop
f.Close
```

Comment: The second one example works fine for me but it deletes every file older than the rest 10 but I wanted to delete files only with extension '.bac' (list of 10 most recent files should also be created onl with files with ext. '.bac'. And the second problem is that I have to run this code twice otherwise it didn't delete files. About first example: It didn't run for me, it keeps telling me that: "Index out of range: i" Code of error: 800A0009. If it's possible to explain me where i have put what fragment it'll be great help. I'm not good at programing.

Comment: See updated answer. You need to add a filter to the command in the second example, and the first example had an off-by-one error in the loop filling the dictionary..

Comment: Still no luck :( First example delete everything but '.bac' but my target is keep everything and 10 latest '.bac' files (in simple way delete every '.bac' file except 10 latest files with extension '.bac')
Second example keeps throwing me errors: Line: 7 Character: 59
Error: Syntax error
Code: 800A03EA

Comment: Sorry, made a typo when updating the second example. Fixed. As for the first example: you just need to make the condition in the delete loop check if the file has that particular extension and isn't present in the lookup table. Consider that your homework.

Comment: Not exactly, it's job in my work, employee ordered me a job to create a script which will delete old copies of db to prevent drive fillment.
I forgot to tell you that my files used special characters (national letters) so second example throws me errors

Comment: I tried like you said to make condition in delete loop to check extension (first example) but It's stil telling me about error: Line: 15 Char:42 Error: Needed object: 'mostRecent(...)'
Code: 800A01A8
Delete loop looks like:
For Each f in fso.GetFolder(fldr).Files
  If Not lut.Exists(f.Name) And fso.GetExtensionName(lut) = "bac" Then f.Delete
Next

Tell me if something is wrong

Comment: The condition for shifting existing elements in the list needs to check if the array element is *not* empty. Fixed.

Comment: Almost done, now error in Line: 26 Char: 38 Error: Wrong number of arguments or incorrect assignment properties: 'lut.Add' Code: 800A01C2

Comment: *\*slaps self\** Adding to a dictionary requires key *and* value, of course.